# How to correctly initialize the Windows desktop (explorer.exe) of Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, windows-8

I need to develop a very little application for Windows 8.1 which should consists in very few lines of code because the only purpose is to initialize the Windows 8 OS desk (not startscreen) after a 3rd party program has killed the explorer.exe.

I'll explain this better:

I've did an unatended installation of Windows 8 which need to silently install a specific program (the program is [StartIsBackPlus](http://www.startisback.com/)), to install the program silently the author says to execute the installer with the parameter `/silent`:

```
StartIsBackPlus_Setup.exe /Silent
```

Well, if you didn't noticed the program is a Windows Start-Button replacament for Windows 8.1, and the problem that I have is that after the silent install of this program has finished, the program kills/closes the "desk" (the explorer.exe process) and the taskbar and the wall disappears, it only shows a solid color background.

To solve this problem, I mean to manually re-initialize the desk, is so easy as open the taskmanager and run a new process (explorer.exe), but as I said this need to be totally unatended and at the moment that I try to reproduce this step (for exaple silently open explorer.exe from CMD or from a developed .NET app) it just opens a new explorer window, I can't understand why the CMD only opens a explorer window but If I launch the explorer.exe process from the TaskManager it re-initializes the entire desk correctly.

Then I need to write a method to re-initialize the elements of the windows desk (explorer and taskbar) like the TaskManager does when manualy running explorer.exe, after this problematic 3rd party program has been installed.

...But is not so easy as start the explorer.exe process for example with the `Process.Start` method because I've tried it and it only opens a new explorer window, the desk remains dissapeared, then a simple Process.Start("Explorer.exe") doesn't initializes correctly the Windows desk in this scenery.

Then... what is the right way to initialize the Windows desk after a 3rd party program like this kills the explorer.exe?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

Comment: As @L.B is trying to say - it sounds like you have a different problem - you shouldn't need to initialize windows desk, but find a way to stop whatever it is from killing it in the first place (or something else) perhaps?

Comment: @Chris I'll explain that details, the application is a StartButton installer, it replaces the windows 8 startbutton and after the installation it closes the explorer.exe (the screen goes solid color it removes the taskbar too), then If I just re-start the explorer.exe process the desk elements doesn't initializes it only opens a new explorer window.

Comment: *This is because I did a custom silent installer for an application that after be installed automatically closes the explorer.exe,* IIRC ClassicShell installs without killing explorer so perhaps do what it does ... And don't kill explorer...

Comment: @ta.speot.is thanks for comment but using ClassicShell replacament is not a solution for me, I need to use the software that I've commented I've paid for it

Comment: @ElektroStudios I didn't say use ClassicShell, I said *do what it does*

Comment: @xpda - I think a lot of the downvote heat came from the original question (which was rather unclear) and insulting comments that followed, not due to any unusuality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from memory, but try this:

```
 myProcess = New Process()
 myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"
 myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
 myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath
 myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

 myProcess.Start()
```

I have to say, I think this is probably something the author should know about/deal with.  Get your $3 worth in support ;)

Comment: It worked fine, I can't understand the differences between why setting a startinfo worked (all the desk is re-initialized) and without setting the startinfo don't worked (only a new explorer window is opened), maybe is because the ShellExecute property? anyways thanks!

Comment: I think maybe it is due to the `CreateNoWindow`: explorer assumes the desktop stuff is being requested or that is all it knows to do with NoWindow

Comment: CreateNoWindow has nothing to do with this working: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow(v=vs.110).aspx "If the UseShellExecute property is true or the UserName and Password properties are not null, the CreateNoWindow property value is ignored and a new window is created."

Comment: apparently that is not the case with explorer.exe: all those are true, but an explorer window is not created.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of my very little tool to re-initialize the desktop correctly, maybe it can be improved more (with better elements checks than the TaskBar) ...I know, but this works well at least in my case:

```
#Region " Imports "

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports RefreshExplorer.NativeMethods

#End Region

''' <summary>
''' Initializes a new instance of Explorer process.
''' </summary>
Module RefreshExplorer

#Region " P/Invoke "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Class NativeMethods.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Class NativeMethods

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Retrieves a handle to the top-level window whose class name and window name match the specified strings. 
        ''' This function does not search child windows. 
        ''' This function does not perform a case-sensitive search.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="lpClassName">
        ''' The class name or a class atom created by a previous call to the 
        ''' RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx function.
        ''' The atom must be in the low-order word of lpClassName; 
        ''' the high-order word must be zero.
        ''' If lpClassName points to a string, it specifies the window class name. 
        ''' The class name can be any name registered with RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx, 
        ''' or any of the predefined control-class names.
        ''' If lpClassName is NULL, it finds any window whose title matches the lpWindowName parameter.
        ''' </param>
        ''' <param name="zero">
        ''' The window name (the window's title). 
        ''' If this parameter is NULL, all window names match.</param>
        ''' <returns>IntPtr.</returns>
        <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="FindWindow", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
        Public Shared Function FindWindowByClass(
            ByVal lpClassName As String,
            ByVal zero As IntPtr
        ) As IntPtr
        End Function

    End Class

#End Region

#Region " ReadOnly Strings "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the directory where the Explorer process is located.
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly ExplorerDirectory As String =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the filename of the process.
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly ExplorerFilename As String = "Explorer.exe"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the desk Taskbar Class-name.
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly TaskBarClassName As String = "Shell_TrayWnd"

#End Region

#Region " Process "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The explorer process.
    ''' </summary>
    Dim Explorer As New Process With
    {
     .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With
                  {
                   .FileName = Path.Combine(ExplorerDirectory, ExplorerFilename),
                   .WorkingDirectory = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath,
                   .UseShellExecute = True
                  }
    }

#End Region

#Region " Main "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Defines the entry point of the application.
    ''' </summary>
    Sub Main()

        Select Case Convert.ToBoolean(CInt(FindWindowByClass(TaskBarClassName, Nothing)))

            Case False ' The Taskbar is not found.

                Try
                    Explorer.Start()
                    Console.WriteLine("Windows Explorer has been re-initialized successfully")
                    Environment.Exit(0)

                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    Environment.Exit(1)

                End Try

            Case True ' The Taskbar is found.
                Console.WriteLine("Can't proceed, Windows Explorer is currently running. Exiting...")
                Environment.Exit(2)

        End Select

    End Sub

#End Region

End Module
```